# window.onload work but Chrome console says: Uncaught TypeError: window.onload is not a function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I want to run `getLocation()` method at the page load. I added: `window.onload(getLocation());` and the function is invoked as I desire but Chrome console says:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: window.onload is not a function(anonymous function) @ (index):116
```

---

The view, the `window.onload(getLocation());` is at the bottom:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}


<div id="demo"></div>
<h2>Gecoding Demo JavaScript: </h2>
<div id="map" style="height: 253px ; width: 253px" />


@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
        var x = document.getElementById("demo");
        function getLocation() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                var position = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);

            } else {
                x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
            }
        }
        function showPosition(position) {
            x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
            "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
            InitializeMap(position)
        }
        var map;
        var geocoder;
        function InitializeMap(position) {

            alert(position.coords.latitude+"");
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            var myOptions =
            {
                zoom: 8,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                disableDefaultUI: true
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
        }

        window.onload(getLocation());
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Try `window.onload=getLocation;`

Comment: @NewToJS No errors this time. Why it even worked before? I come from Java,C# world, if sth is wrong it does not work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The way you've written your code, it's not running onload, it's just running when the parser hits it. Because you wrote `getLocation()` rather than just `getLocation`, it executes the function.

If you are certain there will be nothing else to be fired on load, you can do `window.onload=getLocation;`. If you want to make sure you play nicely with other code (including third-party frameworks/libraries) that might use the load event, you can do something like this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', getLocation);
```

Note that that code won't work in IE8. If you need to support IE8, check for `addEventListener()` and if it is not found, check for and use `attachEvent()` instead:

```
   if (window.addEventListener) {
      window.addEventListener('load', getLocation);
   } else if (window.attachEvent) {
      window.attachEvent('onload', getLocation);
   } else { 
      window.onload = getLocation;
   }
```