# Javascript Loading screen - window.onload not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a loading screen for my project. I need the javascript to remove the CSS property "Display: none" from (page) I can't figure out why my code doesn't work.

**The Problem was:**

window.onload is not a function and i should use something like
"window.onload = loader;" instead. Afterwards I should make it "display:inline"

Worked perfectly!

```js
window.onload(loader)

function loader(){
    document.getElementById("page").style.removeProperty("display");
}
```

```css
#page{
    display: none;
}


/* Loading */
#loading{
    width: 100%;
    height:100vh;
    background-color: #428BCA;
}

.loading_container{
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#spin {
border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
    border-top: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

#loading h1{
    color: #FFF;
    margin-left:10px; 
}
```

```html
<div id="page">

Content!

</div>
<div id="loading">
  <div class="loading_container">
  <div id="spin"></div>
  <h1>Loading...</h1>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there an error you are getting?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29927638/window-onload-work-but-chrome-console-says-uncaught-typeerror-window-onload-is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

window.onload is not a function.

You need to assign it to the function as follows.

`window.onload = loader;`

I'm assuming you want the loading animation to disappear upon successfully loading. The snippet in the **loader()** function emulates loading by waiting 3 seconds.

I set the css attributes differently. You initialise #page to `display: none`, so I simply set it to the default value inline.

`document.getElementById("page").style.display = "inline";`

I would favor this method instead of removing the attribute entirely and letting it default. This way you can specify a particular display value of your desire. I.e. inline-block, block etc.

```js
window.onload = loader;

function loader(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("loading").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("page").style.display = "inline";
    }, 3000);
}
```

```css
#page{
    display: none;
}


/* Loading */
#loading{
    width: 100%;
    height:100vh;
    background-color: #428BCA;
}

.loading_container{
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#spin {
border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
    border-top: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

#loading h1{
    color: #FFF;
    margin-left:10px; 
}
```

```html
<div id="page">

Content!

</div>
<div id="loading">
  <div class="loading_container">
  <div id="spin"></div>
  <h1>Loading...</h1>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem.  I'm not sure how new your are to JavaScript. But please understand that the `setTimeout()` function is simply used here to emulate time taken to do *some task*.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to show the content of the page with the function 'loader', correct? If so, you can't try to get rid of the `display` property, because it needs to be set. You want to change it from `none` to `initial` or `inline`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `window.onload` is not a function. It's a property. You can simply assign your callback to it. 
 `removeProperty("display");` is also wrong. It should be `style.display = "none"`

```js
window.onload = loader;

function loader() {
  document.getElementById("page").style.display = "none";
}

loader();
```

```css
#page {
  display: none;
}


/* Loading */

#loading {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #428BCA;
}

.loading_container {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#spin {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  /* Light grey */
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  /* Blue */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

#loading h1 {
  color: #FFF;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">

    Content!

  </div>
  <div id="loading">
    <div class="loading_container">
      <div id="spin"></div>
      <h1>Loading...</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
```