# Phonegap CRUD operations - window.openDatabase

Tags: sqlite, cordova, phonegap

Am trying to create a CRUD operation using phonegap/cordova, and I keep receiving "Uncaught DOMException: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent. at window.onload - Line 17" pointing to =>"db = window.openDatabase("employee",  "1.1", "LearnToProgram", 200000);". This further affects db.transaction Line 25 “Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transaction' of undefined”, because Database was not created. Do I need any SQLLite plugin on maybe there is something else missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <title>SQLLite DB App</title>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        var db;

        window.onload=function()
        {
            document.getElementById('btnSave').addEventListener('click', saveData);
            db = window.openDatabase("employees",  "1.0", "LearnToProgram", 200000);
        }

        function saveData(e)
        {



            db.transaction(saveRecord, onSuccess, onError);
        }

        function saveRecord(transaction)
        {
            var name= document.getElementById('name').value;
            var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
            transaction.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employeesList (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Name TEXT NOT NULL, Email TEXT NOT NULL) ');

            var sql= "INSERT INTO employeesList (Name,Email) VALUES ('" + name +"', '" + email + "')";
            console.log(sql);
            transaction.executeSql(sql);
        }

        function onSuccess()
        {
            console.log("Record Saved");
        }

        function onError(error)
        {
            console.log("SQL error: " + error.code);
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header"><h1>Database Storage</h1></div>
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" />
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" />
        <button id="btnSave" type="submit">Save</button>
        <button id="showList">Show Employees</button>

        </div><!-- main-->
        </div><!-- page -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe I help you.

To open a database:

```
var db = null;

document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
  db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({
    name: 'my.db',
    location: 'default',
  });
});
```

IMPORTANT: Like with the other Cordova/phonegap plugins your application must wait for the deviceready event. This is especially tricky in Angular/ngCordova/Ionic controller/factory/service callbacks which may be triggered before the deviceready event is fired.

Comment: I implemented something similar but still giving same error



 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
  
  var db;
  
   function onDeviceReady() {
   //alert("device ready");
    db = window.openDatabase("employees",  "1.0", "LearnToProgram", 200000);
    db.transaction(createDB, errorCB, successCB);
   }

Comment: Yes, I checked this using the alert and I was receiving it. The problem is why Database isn't being created

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29927638/window-onload-work-but-chrome-console-says-uncaught-typeerror-window-onload-is?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Checked that link, its a bit different from what I seek. I think my problem is why database isn't being created. The load activity is just okay

Comment: still at it? Have you build something like that before

Comment: yo pude usar el plugin https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage. y funciona bien. si queres te paso como lo tengo por mail

Comment: I keep receiving "database not open" Even after using the guide above. Can you email me mountainclimbing1@gmail.com.