# document.querySelector() does not working

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any dependency problem?
because I am using the only pure javascript there is no jquery or anything.
Using node.js
Here is my code

```js
window.onload()=function(){
  var left=document.querySelector('.left');
  var right=document.querySelector(".right");

  var container=document.querySelector(".container");   
  console.log(left);
  left.addEventListener('mouseenter',()=>{
      container.classList.add('hover-left');

  })
  left.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
      container.classList.remove('hover-left');
  })
  right.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
      container.classList.add('hover-right');
  })
  right.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
      container.classList.remove('hover-right');
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="split left">
        <h1>The Designer</h1>
        <a href="" class="button">Read more</a>
    </div>
    <div class="split right">
        <h1>The Programmer</h1>
        <a href="" class="button">Read more</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _"does not working"_ is as inaccurate as possible... Please describe what should happen, what happens instead and if there are any errors in the console and post them here with the complete error message.

Comment: try removing the `()` from `window.onload() = ...` use just `window.onload = function...`

Comment: here it is Uncaught TypeError: window.onload is not a function

Comment: So, did you tried my suggestion above?

Comment: then its giving Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at this.

Comment: actually problem is document.querySelector() its not reading anything

Comment: `document.querySelector(".container")` is fine but I think you execute your script before the dom is rendered. Try moving the `<script>...</script>` block just before `</body>` and you don't need the window.onload anymore.

Comment: @KrishSingh did you see my answer?

Comment: Once you get rid of that extra `()`, your code works perfectly. https://jsfiddle.net/ke1b0pfo/

Answer (score 3):

If you have any static JS files being loaded in the  tag in your html requesting to please load the JS at the end of the html body. Document wont be ready until the JS is loaded hence the document will be null.

Comment: This was the cause when I ran into this issue. I'm now putting the relevant lines of JS code in the construct: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ ... }`

Answer (score 1):

I got this error on Chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: window.onload is not a function
```

Removing the parentheses the error was gone.

But i didn't get how your page should work.

Look for more information here:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29927638/window-onload-work-but-chrome-console-says-uncaught-typeerror-window-onload-is](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29927638/window-onload-work-but-chrome-console-says-uncaught-typeerror-window-onload-is)

Answer (score 0):

If you select your DOM Elements with the CSS-Selector '.' for classes you get a list of elements instead of a single element which you can directly manipulate.

If left, right and container only appear once on your page, it's best to use ids:

JS:

```
window.onload=function(){
    var left=document.getElementById('left');
    var right=document.getElementById("right");

    var container=document.getElementById("container");   
    console.log(left);
    left.addEventListener('mouseenter',()=>{
        container.classList.add('hover-left');

    })
    left.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
        container.classList.remove('hover-left');
    })
    right.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
        container.classList.add('hover-right');
    })
    right.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
        container.classList.remove('hover-right');
    })
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container" class="container">
   <div class="split" id="left">
      <h1>The Designer</h1>
      <a href="" class="button">Read more</a>
   </div>
   <div class="split" id="right">
      <h1>The Programmer</h1>
      <a href="" class="button">Read more</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Also as a comment above points out you mustn't use brackets when setting onload event.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: `querySelector` only returns a single element.

Comment: here querySelector return null. In the browser console its working fine